# Why does index match get wrong result in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

[image]

The formula that I use is

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(K2,A:A)*(B:B=L2),0)
```

Comment: What version are you using?  Not sure of what you need without a helper column (XLOOKUP if you've got 365).  `Match` by default uses the match type of `1 = Finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use SUMPRODUCT instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT(A2:A7=F2),INT(B2:B7=G2),C2:C7)
```

A2:A7=F2 returns an array of TRUE/FALSE indicating if the item in the array matches the SYMBOL being searched for. Wrapping this in INT converts it to 1/0. The same approach is used in the second parameter to find the rows with the correct dates. The third parameter is the array of prices.

The SUMPRODUCT function multiplies each array with each other, then sums the resulting array. You can see the breakdown in columns J through N in my image above.

Answer (score 0):

What is going wrong is that `MATCH()` is returning a single value, the row in column A that it finds the first match in. This is then multiplied by the array produced by the column B test to produce 0's and "1*whatever row in A produced the first match."

Only the second half of that is going as you expect. The first half, you presumably wanted a similar array so you'd get the arrays multiplied, element by element, producing only non-zero values for matching both criteria.

So since the first row matches in the `MATCH()` function, you get that row for the `INDEX()` function. Internally to your formula, that gives you 0's, mostly, and that row number (1 in this case) times a 1 for any rows that match the date. Something following this pattern:  {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} and the multiplication produces the same thing since it is 1's being multiplied. (If the first match had been row 3 of the column, it would be like this, but 3's instead of 1's.)

Then, if you have a version of Excel with `SPILL` functionality, you get an array the size of your range (a million+ elements...). Without `SPILL`, you get a single value returned if you enter the formula normally (pressing `Enter`). If you have just the one cell, or selected a range, then used `{CSE}` (CSE = Control-Shift-Enter), you'd get the one cell, or all of the selected range, returning elements from the final array. That would be odd looking, as would its `SPILL` equivalent, as you have to remember, it would match the date criterion rows, not the code rows.

The fact you do not mention either `SPILL` output OR having entered it as an array formula suggests you have an older version and entered it "normally" in a single cell.

In that case, it is only presenting the first output of the array. Since the first row of the data actually matches the code looked up, you get an apparently meaningful result which, though wrong, misleads you into thinking things just need some subtle little tweak to be perfect. But this is not so. (If that first one hadn't been a match, you'd likely not have thought it was "oh-so-close" but this happens, eh?)

You need a whole different approach for the first column. And I do NOT mean just not using whole columns as I assume that was just to make the gist of the formula easy for us to grasp. When I use whole columns, Excel never stops calculating during the 4-5 minutes I was willing to wait! So I DO mean "think about THAT" in general, but the main point is you need to build that first array in a different manner, one that returns an array that matches the array the test on column B produces rather than the single value ("single element array" to expand how you regard that). Then things will go swimmingly.

That is what `FlexYourData` is doing, showing you a way to create that array.

So it all comes down, really to the fact that `MATCH()` produces a SINGLE value. (The first matching row in the data's index number in the data (which happens to match the row number here, but wouldn't if the data were in, say, A34:A23048), not an array with only ALL the matches' index numbers, or all of them with 0's interspersed where cells do not match.) And since you needed an array for what you were trying to do, it just is flat out NOT the function to use.